# Grep total amount of specific elements based on date

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way in linux to filter multiple files with bunch of data in one command **without** writing a script?

For this example I want to know how many males appear by date. Also the problem is that a specific date (January 3rd) appears in 2 seperate files:

file1

```
Jan  1 john male=yes
Jan  1 james male=yes
Jan  2 kate male=no 
Jan  3 jonathan male=yes
```

file2

```
Jan  3 alice male=no
Jan  4 john male=yes 
Jan  4 jonathan male=yes
Jan  4 alice male=no
```

I want the total amount of males for each date from all files. If there are no males for a specific date, no output will be given.

```
Jan  1 2 
Jan  3 1
Jan  4 2
```

The only way I can think of is count the total amount of male genders given a specific date, but this would not performant as in real-world examples there could be much more files and manually entering all the dates would be a waste of time. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
localhost:~# cat file1 file2 | grep "male=yes" | grep "Jan  1" | wc -l
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -h 'male=yes' file? | \
    cut -c-6 | \
    awk '{c[$0] += 1} END {for(i in c){printf "%6s %4d\n", i, c[i]}}'
```

The `grep` will print the male lines, `cut` will remove everything but the first 6 chars (date) and `awk` will count every date and printout every date and the counter in the end.

Given your files the output will be:

```
Jan  1    2
Jan  3    1
Jan  4    2
```